# How can list files in /data directory by using root privilege?

Tags: java, android, unix

I use

```
File[]dirs = f.listFiles();
```

for normal files and folders. But for `/data` it returns `null`.

I think because it is a root directory. How can read/write these files with root permission?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the libraries RootShell and RootTools (available at Github, just do a simple google search) to your project and read the documentation at the wiki on the same pages to see how to execute code for rooted users and all that stuff. I hope I helped you ^^